# Alternative way to store values to an array dynamically w.r.t the deprecated code to do the same

Tags: php, arrays, email, object

I'm working on a project version upgrade whereby emails are being fetched from Gmail and stored to database.

I'm seekng the alternative for line no.

> "$this->_walk($obj, &$msg[], $main_content_type);"

as this doesn't work in new versions of PHP.

Is there any work around to achieve  the same result which is a single array of all mail values?

```
    function _walk( $object, $msg, $main_content_type = "" )
    {
        if ( !isset( $object->parts ) )
        {
            $ctype = "";
            $ctype = trim( $object->ctype_primary ) . "/" . trim( $object->ctype_secondary );

            if ( isset( $object->disposition ) && ( !strcasecmp( trim( $object->disposition ), "attachment" ) || ( !strcasecmp( trim( $object->disposition ), "inline" ) && ( ( strcasecmp( $ctype, "text/plain" ) && strcasecmp( $ctype, "text/html" ) ) ) ) ) )
            {
                $ctype .= trim( $object->disposition );
            }

            switch ( strtolower( $ctype ) )
            {
                case "text/html":
                    $msg .= $object->body;
                    break;

                case "text/plain":
                    $enc = $object->headers[ 'content-transfer-encoding' ];
                    if ( $enc != "quoted-printable" ) {
                        $msg .= nl2br( $object->body );
                    } else {
                        $msg .= html_entity_decode( $object->body );
                    }
                    break;

                case "image/jpeg":
                case "image/gif":
                case "image/jpg":
                case "image/bmp":
                    $name = trim( $object->headers[ 'name' ] );
                    $cid  = trim( $object->headers[ 'content-id' ] );
                    $cid  = str_ireplace( "<", "", $cid );
                    $cid  = str_ireplace( ">", "", $cid );

                    if ( empty( $name ) )
                        trim( strtok( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], "=" ) );
                    $name = trim( strtok( "=\"" ) );

                    if ( empty( $name ) ) {
                        $name = $cid . "." . substr( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], strrpos( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], "/" ) + 1 );
                    }

                    $temp = $this->mailFolder . "/tmp/";
                    $name = mt_rand( 100, 999999 ) . "_" . $name;
                    @mkdir( $temp, 777 );
                    $tmpfile = $temp . $name;
                    $fp      = fopen( $tmpfile, "w" );
                    fwrite( $fp, $object->body );
                    fclose( $fp );
                    $msg .= $name;
                    break;

                default:
                    $name = trim( $object->headers[ 'name' ] );
                    if ( isset( $object->headers[ 'content-id' ] ) ) {
                        $cid       = trim( $object->headers[ 'content-id' ] );
                        $cid       = str_ireplace( "<", "", $cid );
                        $cid       = str_ireplace( ">", "", $cid );
                        $extension = substr( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], strpos( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], "/" ) + 1, strpos( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], ";" ) - strpos( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ], "/" ) - 1 );
                        $name      = $cid . "." . $extension;
                    }

                    if ( isset( $object->ctype_parameters[ 'name' ] ) ) {
                        $name = trim( $object->ctype_parameters[ 'name' ] );
                    }

                    if ( empty( $name ) && isset( $object->d_parameters[ 'filename' ] ) ) {
                        $name = trim( $object->d_parameters[ 'filename' ] );
                    }

                    if ( empty( $name ) && strrpos( trim( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ] ), "=" ) !== FALSE ) {
                        $name = substr( trim( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ] ), strrpos( trim( $object->headers[ 'content-type' ] ), "=" ) + 2, -1 );
                    }

                    if ( empty( $name ) ) {
                        $name = 'ForwardedMessage.eml';
                    }

                    $temp = $this->mailFolder . "/tmp/";
                    $name = mt_rand( 100, 999999 ) . "_" . $name;
                    @mkdir( $temp, 777 );
                    $tmpfile = $temp . $name;
                    $fp      = fopen( $tmpfile, "w" );
                    fwrite( $fp, $object->body );
                    fclose( $fp );
                    $msg .= $name;
                    break;
            }
        } else {

            foreach ( $object->parts as $obj ) {
                $this->_walk( $obj, &$msg[], $main_content_type );
            }
        }
        return $msg;
    }
```

Comment: since PHP 5.3/5.4 you need to declare the reference in the function declaration, but not when you call the function. But you could also just get the return value: `$msg = $this->_walk($obj, $msg, $main_content_type);`

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, it does work but I need the result as an array format; not as string. There's a workaround to add some text before every $msg and then explode to convert to array. But I'm seeking some credible solution.